# Provider class org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run this code but it can't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcSYw.png)

**Code:**

```java
package newproject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\selenium-java-3.141.59\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() ;
        driver.get("http://webdunia.com");
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
>   C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar Caused by:
>   java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class
>   org.eclipse.jetty.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder not in module

What is the solution for this?

Comment: you should better paste your code ant the error message here.

Comment: Sir @HakanDilek, I have already posted the actual code and output. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I found one SO question for the same issue and that has an excepted answer.

Comment: Sir @AndreasDolk, should I downgrade from Java 14 to Java 8u?

Comment: That probably solves your problem. Yes. If it's OK for you to run the selenium tests with java 8, then go for that. Or check with selenium if they have a version that runs with java 9+ and use that one instead.